# Categories not selected correctly with if statements

Tags: categories, conditionals

Currently I'm trying to use if statements to determine what category to filter on. I'm using a combination of freebie and embed.
However, I can't seem to find the right syntax to filter correctly. I have tried different orders for the if statements.

Broken:
    {exp:channel:entrieschannel="resources" {if freebie_break_1}category='{freebie_break_1}'{if:else embed:category}category='{embed:category}'{/if}   {if freebie_break_2}category2="{freebie_break_2}"{/if}... normal channel params}

Works:

```
{if embed:category}category='{embed:category}'{/if}
```

Can someone let me know if category selection simply won't allow me to have this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can 't use freebie this way because the freebie segments are parsed after the Channel Module.

My suggestion is to use freebie before the embed, on the parent template.

I tried to suggest you a code, but I couldn't figure what is the `category2` parameter.

This is the closest I could get:

```
{embed="foo/bar"
    {if freebie_break_1}
        category="{freebie_break_1}"
    {if:else}
        category="DEFAULT_CATEGORY"
    {/if}
}
```

Comment: I decided to go this way. I inherited a template and tried to consolidate them. I have ended up creating a parent template just for routing to the main template.